# How to use string as an expression in SSRS reports

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have created a SSRS report in which I have used a tablix and a single dataset (ds_test)

Now the dataset use t-sql and  is calling a table in which has data as shown below:

"IIF(1=1,True,False)"

What I am trying to do is to use this as an expression inside the cell of the tablix. But when I run the report It give me:

IIF(1=1,True,False)

But It should show the result as "True", I know it is taking this as a string but is there any way so that we can use this as an expression in the report

NOTE: We cannot use this directly in report , because this is generated dynamically and should always present in DB tables only

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you be more specific.. is it hardcoded in the expression or it is going to be column value output from SQL Server

Comment: AFAIK there is no equivalent to VBScript's Eval() in .NET. Alternatives are: invent your own parser; use something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3445/Runtime-Compilation-A-NET-eval-statement  and jump through the requisite hoops to get working with Reporting Services